# How to stop the page postback using updatepanel

Tags: c#, ajax

I am using C#, Ajax for coding.

Please see below code which I am using for ajax implementation.

```
<div id="column2Container">
            <ajax:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </ajax:ScriptManager>
            <div id="column2">
                 <ajax:UpdateProgress ID="uprogDestinationsTabs" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upDestinationTabs">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <span style="display: block; text-align: center">
                            <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: larger; font-weight: bold;">
                                <img src="/Images/ajax-loader-circle-thickbox.gif" alt="Processing..." /><br />
                                <br />
                                Processing...</p>
                        </span>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </ajax:UpdateProgress>
                <ajax:UpdatePanel ID="upDestinationTabs" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <CCIT.Web:DestinationTabs runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajax:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
</div>
```

Actually what I am trying to do is that, you can see there is an .net usercontrol used inside updatepanel i.e. `<CCIT.Web:DestinationTabs runat="server" />` this user control will render below html

```
<ul class="tabHead tabs-nav">
    <li class="tabLeftEnd"></li>
    <li id="tab-1">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/index.aspx"><span>Overview</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs-selected" id="tab-2">
    <a href="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/guide.aspx"><span>Guide</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3">
    <a href="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/flightschedule.aspx"><span>Flight Schedule</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4">
    <a href="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/specialOffers.aspx"><span>Special Offers</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/photo.aspx"><span>Photos</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabRightEnd"></li>
</ul>
```

Now what I am trying to do is that when ever user will click any of these links that should be handled from Ajax, I mean there would not be any page postback while loading these pages i.e. why I am trying to use update panel.

Please suggest what is wrong in the above ajax implementation as the above code is not working for me.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what a postback is. A postback is when the contents of a form are sent to the server for processing. When a user clicks on one of your links it isn't a postback. Nothing is being sent back to the server - they are just navigating to a new page.

Having the links in an updatepanel is not going to prevent the screen from refreshing or 'flickering' when the user navigates to a new page. The only time this would make a difference is if you were causing a postback (ex. clicking a button).

The only way to prevent the screen from refreshing while navigating from page to page would be to get the contents of a page using AJAX (not an update panel) and load that into a div.

You could use jquery's load function to do this:

1) Add a reference to jquery to your page

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
```

2) Add a div to your page called called divContent

```
<div id="divContent"></div>
```

3) Add this bit of javascript to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadPage(url) {
        $('#divContent').load(url, 'divContent');
    }
</script>
```

4) Make your links look like this:

```
<a href="javascript: LoadPage('path/to/page.aspx');"><span>Guide</span></a>
```

Comment: No, it is not a post back for sure.

Comment: many thanks @keviv for your suggestions, i have already tried above jquery logic in my page but it was taking more time in loading, so that i was trying ajax updatepanel to avoid the page load, can you please suggest how i can achieve this using updatepanel so that whole page does not seems loading as i am also having .net usercontrol on the pages